# React-Native - Unable to resolve module fs from node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine/cli-engine.js

Tags: react-native, eslint, yarnpkg

I have this react-native app that worked just fine, but suddenly I get this error:

```
error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `fs` from `node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine/cli-engine.js`: fs could not be found within the project.
```

The first time that I got it, I was just testing the app, doing things I have been doing all day, nothing new, nothing unusual. Now I can't even start the app on my device.

I start the app with this script: `yarn start-fresh` from my package.json:

```
"start-fresh": "cd android/ && ./gradlew clean && cd .. && rm -rf node_modules/ && yarn install && react-native start --reset-cache"
```

Then in a new terminal tab, I do `yarn android`. It loads everything fine in this 2nd tab, but then when I go back to the first tab(where I ran `yarn start-fresh`), it loads some stuff but then I get the error. I don't remember installing any new package or update the packages or anything like that...

I tried searching online for solutions but I couldn't find anything helpful. Also, after the error I have this list:

```
If you are sure the module exists, try these steps:
 1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
 2. Delete node_modules: rm -rf node_modules and run yarn install
 3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
 4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*
```

I tried everything that is listed there, but none worked.

Could anyone help me make this app work again?

Comment: are you using react-native-fs in your code ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, are you using VSCode?
I think there is auto imported module in your code while you're coding. In the vscode, if you type something, then it suggests auto-import and maybe you import unused modules.
Please check the codes that you have unused modules.

Comment: OMG... I feel so dumb... I think you're right... I just went back to the last working push request on my project, and it worked like that. I'm pretty sure I just typed fs somewhere by mistake and this is why it wasn't working. Anyway, I just made it work, but I think this was the cause. Thank you for your time tho. :)

Comment: I'm speechless... I spent over 6 hours on this problem. This was the solution. Removed a completely random import and it works again. Thank you for this! And: Well done VSCode...